# In react, how to get noticed when children change?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I am making this class called `Scrollable` which enables scrolling if the width/height of the children elements exceeds a certain value. Here is the code.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

const INITIAL = 'initial';

class Scrollable extends Component {
  render() {
    let outter_styles = {
      overflowX: (this.props.x? 'auto': INITIAL),
      overflowY: (this.props.y? 'auto': INITIAL),
      maxWidth: this.props.width || INITIAL,
      maxHeight: this.props.height || INITIAL,
    };
    return (
      <div ref={el => this.outterEl = el} style={outter_styles}>
        <div ref={el => this.innerEl = el}>
          {this.props.children}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
};

export default Scrollable;

// To use: <Scrollable y><OtherComponent /></Scrollable>
```

This works great. Except now I wish to add one more functionality which makes the scrollable always scroll to the bottom. I have some idea of how to do it:

```
this.outterEl.scrollTop = this.innerEl.offsetHeight;
```

But this only need to be called when `this.props.children` height changes. Is there any idea on how to achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I have an idea of solving this.

Since I am using react-redux. The problem is that I could not use lifecycle hooks on this `Scrollable` component since `this.props.children` might not necessarily be changed when the content is updated.

One way to achieve this is to make `Scroll` component aware of the corresponding values in the redux `state`. So that when that relevant value is updated, we can scroll down to the bottom.

Scrollable component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

const INITIAL = 'initial';

class Scrollable extends Component {
  componentWillUpdate(){
    if(this.props.autoScroll){
      // only auto scroll when the scroll is already at bottom.
      this.autoScroll = this.outterEl.scrollHeight - this.outterEl.scrollTop - Number.parseInt(this.props.height) < 1;
    }
  }

  componentDidUpdate(){
    if(this.autoScroll) this.outterEl.scrollTop = this.outterEl.scrollHeight;
  }

  render() {
    let styles = {
      overflowX: (this.props.x? 'auto': INITIAL),
      overflowY: (this.props.y? 'auto': INITIAL),
      maxWidth: this.props.width || INITIAL,
      maxHeight: this.props.height || INITIAL,
    };
    return (
      <div ref={el => this.outterEl = el} style={styles}>
        <div ref={el => this.innerEl = el}>
            {this.props.children}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
};

export default Scrollable;
```

Scrollable container:

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

import Scrollable from '../components/Scrollable';

const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => Object.assign({
  state: state[ownProps.autoScroll] || false
}, ownProps);

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Scrollable)
```

With this, `Scrollable`'s life cycle hooks will be called when the corresponding state changes.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend a package [element-resize-detector](https://www.npmjs.com/package/element-resize-detector). It is not React-specific but you can easily build a high-order component around it or integrate your Scrollable component with it.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I agree that it's a nice package. However, I am looking for a simpler solution than that, and I think the solution I came up with is cleaner and even easier to reason about. What do you think?

Comment: It really depends. If you simply look for a plain one, it is absolutely fine with what you have.